# How to fix the problem: No module named 'google.protobuf.reflection'

Tags: python, python-3.x

when I import syft in Python3.7, it says: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.protobuf.reflection'`.

when I import TensorFlow, it says: `ImportError: cannot import name 'descriptor' from 'google.protobuf' (unknown location)`.

How to solve these two problems?

The related software information are:

- Mac OSX
- Python3.7.3
- protoc version is 3.8.0
- pip3 is located in:/Users/susan/anaconda3/bin/pip3

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall `google` and `protobuf` and install them again

```
pip uninstall protobuf
pip uninstall google
pip install google 
pip install --upgrade protobuf
```

The most important thing is that you should use the latest stable version of `protobuf`.